# How to check whether a method is defined in apache velocity under Strict Mode

Tags: velocity

Velocity Strict Mode does not allow $!field.extension, how do I check if getExtension() is a method defined in $field?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside velocity tools 2 there's [ClassTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ClassTool.html) class

> This tool is meant to simplify reflective lookup of information about a Class and its Fields, Methods

You can use [getMethods()](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ClassTool.html#getMethods()) function to get all Class methods.